# can't start up rails app for bundle issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to start a rails app and get the following error message:

```
C:\project\ruby\lyc>rails server
You have requested:
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter >= 0

The bundle currently has activerecord-jdbc-adapter locked at 1.0.2.
Try running `bundle update activerecord-jdbc-adapter`
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Since I'm quite new to ROR, the above is totally messy to me. So could any one of you explain to me what happened behind the curtain? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've usually found the following works:

delete (or rename) your Gemfile.lock and then try bundle install

The Gemfile.lock file keeps a list of the current versions of gems that your bundle is using, if you delete it and then re bundle, you can often fix version issues

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/21/named-gem-environments-and-bundler/